# How to create a schedule with condition to run in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-job

I need create a job schedule. My job must be run after table sources from DWH team run are done, but I can't control this. I only can see `table_name` and `complete_run_date_time` in a log table from DWH team.

So please guide me on how to create a job to run my procedure when `complete_run_date_time = sysdate`.

I tried using `If Then Else`, but it can not run.

Comment: its sounds more likely you need a trigger, not a job.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, whatever job scheduler is responsible for loading the data warehouse would spawn your job after completion.  Barring that, I'd just set the job to run every, say, 5 minutes.  If `trunc(complete_run_date_time) = trunc(sysdate)` and your process hasn't run yet today (you may need a new local log table), then run your process.